# sort multiple columns numerically

Tags: shell, sorting

I always wondered how `sort` works when ordering multiple columns according to their numerical values. For example:

```
echo -e " 2 3 \n 1 2 \n 2 10" | sort -n
```

produces:

```
1 2
2 10
2 3
```

and so does `sort -g`. If I want to order numerically the second column as well, the only solution I came up with is:

```
echo -e " 2 3 \n 1 2 \n 2 10" | sort -k1n -k2n
```

which produces the desired output:

```
1 2
2 3
2 10
```

Someone could please explain this behavior and tell if a simpler solution exists?

Comment: "`-g`  Sort numerically, converting a **prefix of each line** to a long double-precision floating point number."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX specification for [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) says:

> `-n`
>   Restrict the sort key to an initial numeric string, consisting of optional `<blank>` characters, optional minus-sign, and zero or more digits with an optional radix character and thousands separators (as defined in the current locale), which shall be sorted by arithmetic value. An empty digit string shall be treated as zero. Leading zeros and signs on zeros shall not affect ordering.

This is essentially the same as saying `-k1n,1`.  If you want to sort by multiple columns numerically, you must say so:

```
sort -k1n,1 -k2n,2 …
```

Be cautious about omitting the 'field end' after the commas.

Comment: Ok, so basically there's no other way than specify the -n option for every columns. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Simpler, (the leading `-k1n` isn't needed), but not by much:

```
echo -e " 2 3 \n 1 2 \n 2 10" | sort -k2n
```

Output:

```
 1 2 
 2 3 
 2 10
```

Comment: That only sorts one column numerically.  The question is about how to sort two columns numerically.  It really isn't answering the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, If the question is interpreted literally, the OP's input seems to be a fuzzy match for the question.   To remove such vagueness, this morning I was considering what would be the shortest and best two-column input to produce four distinct `sort` outputs for the following four options:    1. `-k1n`  2. `-k2n`  3. `-k1n -k2n`  4. `-k2n -k1n`.   Never quite got much past the "considering" stage... but haven't found a 2x3 set that works...

Comment: That's wrong: only by chance the first column is sorted correctly. If you try this second example `echo -e " 10 3 \n 1 2 \n 2 10" | sort -k2n` you realize that in the first column the value 10 is put before 2.

Comment: @WolfNZO, thanks, I was aware of that before posting the answer.  Where we differ is in the presumption that the OP necessarily knew what he wanted.  You suppose the OP wanted two columns sorted, (after all, he said so), whereas I see more room for doubt, given the vagueness of the input data.

Comment: On finding suitably unambiguous input data for `sort`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813821/minimal-two-column-numeric-input-data-for-sort-example-with-distinct-permutat).