# Minimal two column numeric input data for `sort` example, with distinct permutations

Tags: sorting, unix, sh

What's the least number of rows of two-column numeric input needed to produce four unique `sort` outputs for the following four options:
1. `-sn -k1` 2. `-sn -k2` 3. `-sn -k1 -k2` 4. `-sn -k2 -k1` ?

Here's a 6 row example, (with 4 unique outputs):

```
6 5 
3 7 
6 3 
2 7 
4 4 
5 2
```

As a convenience, a function to count those four outputs given 2 columns of numbers, (requires the [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) `pee` command), which prints the number of unique outputs:

```
# Usage: foo c1_1 c2_1 c1_2 c2_2 ...
foo() { echo "$@" | tr  -s '[:space:]' '\n' | paste - - | \
        pee "sort -sn -k1     | md5sum" \
            "sort -sn -k2     | md5sum" \
            "sort -sn -k1 -k2 | md5sum" \
            "sort -sn -k2 -k1 | md5sum" | \
        sort -u | wc -l ; }
```

So to count the unique permutations of this input:

```
8  5
3  5
8  4
```

Run this:

```
foo 8 5 3 1 8 3
```

Output:

```
2
```

(Only two unique outputs.  Not enough...)

---

Note:  This question was inspired by the obscurity of the current version of the `sort` manual, specifically `COLUMNS=65 man sort | grep -A 17 KEYDEF | sed 3,18d`.  The `info sort` page's treatment of *KEYDEF*s is much better.

*KEYDEF*s are more useful than they might first seem.  The `-u` or `--unique` switch works nicely with the *KEYDEF*s, and in effect allows `sort` to delete unwanted redundant lines, and therefore can furnish a more concise substitute for certain `sed` or `awk` scripts and similar pipelines.

Comment: Your 6 row example appears to have varying amounts of whitespace between the numbers. The spacing doesn't look wide enough to represent a tab with the usual 8-column tabstop... but now I see you actually put tabs in the post and that's just what the renderer did with them.

Comment: Ugh, a bug in `foo()`... `foo 1 2 10 9 1 10 2 9` returns `4`, but subtracting *1* in the two larger numbers changes the output, and `foo 1 2  9 8 1  9 2 8` returns `2`.

Comment: You are aware of the last-resort comparison, right? Did you mean to use `-s`? If you didn't want us to play with the whitespace *or* take advantage of the fact that 9 comes after 10 in the last-resort comparison, what exactly was the point?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, nope I was oblivious, but (thanks for the clue! ) am reading up on it in `info sort` *now*...   The inspiration was less *code golf* than noticing ambiguous `sort` input examples in other questions, and hypothesizing that for 4  kinds permutations of numeric sorts there must be some sets that allow 4 possible sorts, etc.  After reading the `info` it seems my mental model incorrectly presumed that the `--stable` option was the default.

Comment: If you're using GNU sort the `--debug` option is very helpful

Comment: So it seems to properly support my own vague assumptions, the `sort`s in `foo()` should include `-sn` options.   The modified convenience function: `foo2 () { echo "$@" | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | paste - - | pee "sort -sn -k1 | md5sum" "sort -sn -k2 | md5sum" "sort -sn -k1 -k2 | md5sum" "sort -sn -k2 -k1 | md5sum" | sort -u | wc -l ; }`  With `foo2()` the former  *6x4* example fails, having only *3* outputs.   Therefore here's a replacement *6x4*: `foo2 6 5 3 7 6 3 2 7 4 4 5 2`, (which does have 4 unique outputs), so the question stands...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it in 3 by varying the whitespace:

```
1 1
 2 1
1  2
```

Your `foo` function doesn't produce this kind of output, but since it was only a "convenience" and not a part of the question proper, I declare this answer correct and minimal!

Sneakier version:

```
2       1
11      1
2       2
```

(The last line contains a tab; the others don't.)

With the `-s` option, I can't exploit non-numeric comparisons, but then I *can* exploit the stability of the sort:

```
1   2
2   1
1   1
```

The `1 1` line goes above both of the others if both fields are compared numerically, regardless of which comparison is done first. The ordering of the two comparisons determines the ordering of the other two lines.

On the other hand, if one of the fields isn't used for comparison, the `1 1` line stays below one of the other lines (and which one that is depends on which field is used for comparison).

Comment: Feh!  Whitespace tweaking is strictly taboo.  `foo 1 1 2 1 1 2` returns `2`.  `foo 2 1 11 1  2 2` returns `3`.   **+1** for perveristy tho'.  I'm doubting 3 rows is possible...

Comment: I already felt like my hands were tied by the constraint that the columns had to be numeric...

Comment: Great!  I didn't believe 2x3 was possible.  It seems you derived that answer not by brute force, but deduction/inference too...

Comment: By the way, since there are 6 possible permutations of 3 lines, you might be interested to know that the other 2 are easily achievable by adding `-r` to the existing single-field sorts: `sort -snr -k1` and `sort -snr -k2`